# Adding Custom Page fields wagtail api returning empty array for related field

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Following the doc at [Adding custom page fields](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#adding-custom-page-fields), im trying to add Todo's to a Task object/page model for them to be queryable via the api (same thing for todos, make parent Task queryable), however, the related field always returns an empty array (I would have expected the related (parent or child) Pages to be in the response:

```
class Task(Page):

    CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(11)]
    sub_order = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=CHOICES)
    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ...
    ]
    
    api_fields = [
        APIField('title'),
        APIField('todos'),
    ]

class Todo(Page):
    
    CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 11)]
    sub_order = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=CHOICES)

    parent_page_types = ['app.Task']

    page = models.ForeignKey('app.Task', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='todos')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ...
    ]

    api_fields = [
        APIField('parent_page_types'),
        APIField('sub_order'),

    ]
```

endpoint: `.../api/v2/pages/?format=json&type=app.Task&fields=*`

Response:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "meta": {
                "type": "app.Task",
                "detail_url": ".../api/v2/pages/18/",
                "html_url": "theURL",
                "slug": "aasdasdsad",
                "show_in_menus": false,
                "seo_title": "",
                "search_description": "",
                "first_published_at": "2019-02-05T14:13:09.596817Z"
            },
            "title": "aasdasdsad",
            "parent_page_types": [
                "app.ParentPageType"
            ],
            "sub_order": 1,
            "todos": [] <-------- EMPTY ?
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE:
the sqlite db doesn't seem to be creating/adding the todos or tasks in the table when I create the records =/ . The field is showing up as null, still troubleshooting

Comment: Your ForeignKeys between Task and Todo seem a bit suspect - you have them going in both directions. Does a task belong to a todo, or vice versa? Are they both supposed to be page types, or is one a sub-object of the other?

Comment: =/ , redid the same exercise, only have 1 foreignkey, todo depends on Task, when i create a task, and then child todo pages, the todos array is always empty, i dont know why ,y db is not populating with the child page id's